# MongoDB - how to set cluster?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-replica-set

My OS = Windows 10.

I have installed 2 MongoDB servers (Community Ed.) on 2 machines in LAN.
How can I set cluster (replica, shards) using these 2 MongoDB?

Comment: A sharded cluster requires at least 3 MongoDB processes. How do you like to setup? Maybe you are looking for replicaset.

Comment: Maybe have a look at https://github.com/Wernfried/mongoDB-oneclick

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit write your answer, I'll mark it

Comment: "Link only" answers are not appreciated here. Making a copy/paste of my Github repository would be an overkill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow the step by step replicaSet guide [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/)

Or the step by step for sharded cluster [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-shard-cluster/)

I assume this is test replicaSet configuration you need in your local network  , then you can follow this steps ( attention no security and no configuration files , just a test replicaSet the easiest way ) :

1. Create data folder:

   server 1: mkdir  \data1  \data2

   server 2: mkdir \data3
2. Start the mongod services and make sure the ports are not blocked in your windows firewall:

   server 1: mongod --replSet rs0 --port 27017 --bind_ip localhost,<hostnames ad/or ip address> --dbpath \data1

   server 1: mongod --replSet rs0 --port 27018 --bind_ip localhost,<hostnames ad/or ip address> --dbpath \data2

   server 2: mongod --replSet rs0 --port 27019 --bind_ip localhost,<hostnames ad/or ip address> --dbpath \data3
3. Access to the first member via mongo shell:

   mongosh --port 27017
4. Init the replicaSet:

   rs.initiate({_id:"rs0",members:[{_id:0,host:":27017"  }]})

( execute the command from the shell )

```
 PRIMARY>
```

( wait until the member elect him self as PRIMARY , the shell prompt will change as shown )

5. Add the other two members:

   PRIMARY> rs.add("host2:port2")

   PRIMARY> rs.add("host3:port3")
6. Check the status:

   rs.status()
   Now you need to see 3x members ( 2x in host1 & 1x in host2 )

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/30783429)

Comment: added simple example

Comment: @R2D2 Thanx for the sample!

Comment: please, note with the above sample everybody in your network can access the database including RANSOMWARE apps so next step is to add security ...